# Host internet site on raspberrypi with SIM7600E HAT

Tags: networking, internet

Ive seen many tutorials on how to host webserver on raspberrypi and then put it online linking it to a domain.

However everyone of those tutorials presumes internet connection with a router. This requires router port forwarding to be able to allow the access from the outside. I am not sure on how to configure my SIM7600E 4g HAT for this purpose.

I was able to install apache and mariadb (sql server). I also adquired a domain (No-IP) which then i linked to the IP Address.

Locally I am able to open my domain name in the browser and I can see my php website. However I am not able to connect from outside the network. I guess the reason for this is firewall or this port settings.

Anyone who knows more about this SIM7600E HAT i appreciate your comments. Or is there a guide to do this with the SIM7600E Hat? I searched everywhere and found nothing.

My apache firewall status reads:

Open SSH ALLOW Anywhere

WWW Full ALLOW Anywhere

OpenSSH (v6) ALLOW Anywhere

WWW Full (v6) ALLOW Anywhere

Thank you!

Comment: Try writing in paragraphs. This is unreadable.